# using d3.csv prevents save of Drupal page

Tags: json, csv, d3.js, drupal, drupal-7

I am attempting to modify a working map which uses json data by adding a csv file to join with the json data. When I attempt to insert the code that should work and to save the page, Drupal refuses to save it. The json command is:

```
 d3.json("/sites/default/d3_files/json/toronto-wards.json", function(error,wards) {
```

if I change it to:

```
d3.json("/sites/default/d3_files/json/toronto-wards.json", function(error,wards) { 
    d3.csv("/csv-pledges", function(error, csv) 

{
    var world = data.features;
    csv.forEach(function(d, i) {
        world.forEach(function(e, j) {
            if (d.ward_no === e.SCODE_NAME) 
            {
                e.NAME = d.ward_no
            } // end ward test
        }) // end world loop loop
    })// end of csv loop
}
) // end d3.csv
```

I can't save it. I can't see anything that would cause this. Can someone help?

Comment: I decided to disable the ckeditor module and I was able to save the page. I'd prefer not to do that but at least I know where the problem resides.

Comment: Adding js on a node is probably not the best way to be doing it.

Comment: I was too optimistic when I said that it worked after I disabled CKEditor ... it is broken again. I'm not sure what you mean by adding js on a node. I have built several nodes with js without problem. This is the first time I have had this sort of difficulty. I want to add it to a node so that it is part of the Drupal site with the themes etc.

Comment: read this page which outlines the best ways to add js to drupal: https://www.drupal.org/node/756722

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try it out.

Comment: I've followed your recommendation but I am getting a Reference Error: d3 is not defined. I've left the following code in the node code: <meta charset="utf-8" /><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script><script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script><script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script><script src="/sites/default/d3_files/category-table.js"></script> How should I fix this?

Comment: I installed the d3 module and followed the instructions to add d3 libraries to the libraries folder  The status report indicates that it is installed correctly but I am still getting this error. When I view the source there is no mention of d3 so something is wrong. I'm going to see if I can get an answer in the Drupal forum for the module.

Comment: Why are you adding jquery and d3 in the node? Crazy. jQuery is already in the page by default in drupal, if you want a later version, use the jquery update module.
Like I said, you should not be adding code in the node body. I am about 99% certain that it is the cause of your problem.
Is the reference error coming from your custom code? If so, how are you adding that?

Comment: I'm prepared to remove jQuery from the code but not d3 since I haven't figured out  how to include it. Since the reference error is to d3 I don't see how it can come from anything other than my custom code (if by that you mean my javascript.) This approach (custom code) works on many other sites where I have developed interactive graphics.

Comment: There are a few reasons why not to add js in the node body (such as it not being aggregated and minified) but of course it's up to you. Good luck

Comment: I got the map to work properly with the javascript in the page, and have no errors saving it with or without ckeditor. I have no idea what caused the original problem with saving the code. Thanks for your suggestions.